# Interlinked Multiple Sliders in SwiftUI

Tags: slider, swiftui

I was wondering whether anyone could help me.

In the app I'm working on, I need to split a value into four different areas and I'd like to do so via four sliders, which control the percentage for each of the areas.

For each `Slider`, I've created an `@State private var sliderAValue = 25` and bound them to the sliders via `Slider(value: $sliderAValue, in: 0...100)`

Clearly, when I change the value of any of the sliders, the other values should also change in order that the total percentage is always 100.

But more importantly, the ratio between the other three values should state the same: eg. if the original split is 30 : 30 : 20 : 20 and the user changes the third element to 40%, then the new split should become 22.5 : 22.5 : 40 : 15.

Applying a `didSet` or a `willSet` on the `State` variables doesn't seem to have any effect, yet I clearly need to store the original ratios somewhere and have them automatically updated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Since the state is of type `Int` what should happen in your example with 22.5? If we convert both 22.5 to 22 the sum would not be 100.

Comment: Apologies, @Qbyte, I didn't make myself clear.  The values stored are `Double` values, but rounded to `Int` in the UI

Comment: What should happen if the user drags one slider to 100 so we have a split of 100 : 0 : 0 : 0 and then to 0? Should to be 0 : 33 : 33 : 33 ?

Comment: Thank you, @Qbyte, that looks like an excellent answer.

Comment: Think I can show to 1 decimal place - which won't remove the problem you've pointed out, but will reduce its impact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can store the bindings to all `State` variables in an array of type `Array<Binding<Double>>`. This allows you to add more sliders if you want without much more code.

[image: Synchronized Sliders]

```
struct Sliders: View {

    @State var value1 = 100.0
    @State var value2 = 0.0
    @State var value3 = 0.0
    @State var value4 = 0.0


    var body: some View {

        // add all bindings which you want to synchronize
        let allBindings = [$value1, $value2, $value3, $value4]

        return VStack {

            Button(action: {
                // Manually setting the values does not change the values such
                // that they sum to 100. Use separate algorithm for this
                self.value1 = 10
                self.value2 = 40
            }) {
                Text("Test")
            }


            Text("\(value1)")
            synchronizedSlider(from: allBindings, index: 0)

            Text("\(value2)")
            synchronizedSlider(from: allBindings, index: 1)

            Text("\(value3)")
            synchronizedSlider(from: allBindings, index: 2)

            Text("\(value4)")
            synchronizedSlider(from: allBindings, index: 3)

        }.padding()
    }


    func synchronizedSlider(from bindings: [Binding<Double>], index: Int) -> some View {
        return Slider(value: synchronizedBinding(from: bindings, index: index),
                      in: 0...100)
    }


    func synchronizedBinding(from bindings: [Binding<Double>], index: Int) -> Binding<Double> {

        return Binding(get: {
            return bindings[index].wrappedValue
        }, set: { newValue in

            let sum = bindings.indices.lazy.filter{ $0 != index }.map{ bindings[$0].wrappedValue }.reduce(0.0, +)
            // Use the 'sum' below if you initially provide values which sum to 100
            // and if you do not set the state in code (e.g. click the button)
            //let sum = 100.0 - bindings[index].wrappedValue

            let remaining = 100.0 - newValue

            if sum != 0.0 {
                for i in bindings.indices {
                    if i != index {
                        bindings[i].wrappedValue = bindings[i].wrappedValue * remaining / sum
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // handle 0 sum
                let newOtherValue = remaining / Double(bindings.count - 1)
                for i in bindings.indices {
                    if i != index {
                        bindings[i].wrappedValue = newOtherValue
                    }
                }
            }
            bindings[index].wrappedValue = newValue
        })

    }

}
```

If you want to synchronize only the sliders for `value1`/`value2` and `value3`/`value4` you can change the code in `body` to:

```
let bindings12 = [$value1, $value2]
let bindings34 = [$value3, $value4]

return VStack {

    Text("\(value1)")
    synchronizedSlider(from: bindings12, index: 0)

    Text("\(value2)")
    synchronizedSlider(from: bindings12, index: 1)

    Text("\(value3)")
    synchronizedSlider(from: bindings34, index: 0)

    Text("\(value4)")
    synchronizedSlider(from: bindings34, index: 1)

}.padding()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using onEditingChanged. The other sliders don't update until you release the one you're editing. (There must of course be a way to pull the calculation out into a function so it's not repeated four times, but it's not coming to me right now.)

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var sliderAValue: Double = 25
    @State private var sliderBValue: Double = 25
    @State private var sliderCValue: Double = 25
    @State private var sliderDValue: Double = 25

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // Slider A
            Slider(value: $sliderAValue, in: 0...100, onEditingChanged: { _ in
                let remaining = self.sliderBValue + self.sliderCValue + self.sliderDValue
                let percentageB = self.sliderBValue / remaining
                let percentageC = self.sliderCValue / remaining
                let percentageD = self.sliderDValue / remaining

                let available = 100 - self.sliderAValue

                self.sliderBValue = available * percentageB
                self.sliderCValue = available * percentageC
                self.sliderDValue = available * percentageD
            })
            Text("Slider A: \(sliderAValue, specifier: "%.1f")")

            // Slider B
            Slider(value: $sliderBValue, in: 0...100, onEditingChanged: { _ in
                let remaining = self.sliderAValue + self.sliderCValue + self.sliderDValue
                let percentageA = self.sliderAValue / remaining
                let percentageC = self.sliderCValue / remaining
                let percentageD = self.sliderDValue / remaining

                let available = 100 - self.sliderBValue

                self.sliderAValue = available * percentageA
                self.sliderCValue = available * percentageC
                self.sliderDValue = available * percentageD
            })
            Text("Slider B: \(sliderBValue, specifier: "%.1f")")

            // Slider C
            Slider(value: $sliderCValue, in: 0...100, onEditingChanged: { _ in
                let remaining = self.sliderAValue + self.sliderBValue + self.sliderDValue
                let percentageA = self.sliderAValue / remaining
                let percentageB = self.sliderBValue / remaining
                let percentageD = self.sliderDValue / remaining

                let available = 100 - self.sliderCValue

                self.sliderAValue = available * percentageA
                self.sliderBValue = available * percentageB
                self.sliderDValue = available * percentageD
            })
            Text("Slider C: \(sliderCValue, specifier: "%.1f")")

            // Slider D
            Slider(value: $sliderDValue, in: 0...100, onEditingChanged: { _ in
                let remaining = self.sliderAValue + self.sliderBValue + self.sliderCValue
                let percentageA = self.sliderAValue / remaining
                let percentageB = self.sliderBValue / remaining
                let percentageC = self.sliderCValue / remaining

                let available = 100 - self.sliderDValue

                self.sliderAValue = available * percentageA
                self.sliderBValue = available * percentageB
                self.sliderCValue = available * percentageC
            })
            Text("Slider D: \(sliderDValue, specifier: "%.1f")")
        }
    }
}
```