# Adapting @State variables and UI to user actions in SwiftUI

Tags: class, foreach, swiftui, slider, state

I am a novice at programming and exploring SwiftUI. I've been tackling a challenge for too long, and hoping that someone can guide me to the right direction!

I want a list of interlinked sliders (as in [Interlinked Multiple Sliders in SwiftUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60060048/interlinked-multiple-sliders-in-swiftui)), but with the number of sliders that change dynamically, depending on actions taken by a user.

For example, a user can choose various items, and later on adjust the percentage variable with sliders (and where these percentages are interdependent as in the linked example).

```
class Items: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var components = [ItemComponent]()
    
    func add(component: itemComponent){
        components.append(component)
        }

}

struct ItemComponent: Hashable, Equatable, Identifiable {
       
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String = ""
    var percentage: Double
}
```

Conceptually, it seems I need to do two things to adapt the linked code:

1. generate an array of Binding with the number of elements equal to Items.Component.EndIndex and
2. assign each Binding to the percentage of each ItemComponent.

I am fumbling on both. For 1., I can easily manually create any number of variables, e.g.

```
@State var value1 = 100
@State var value2 = 100
@State var value3 = 100

let allBindings = [$value1, $value2, $value3]
```

but how do I generate them automatically?

For 2., I can use ForEach() to call the components, or Index, but not both together:

```
ForEach(Items.components){ component in 
    Text("\(component.name)")
    Text("\(component.percentage)")
}

ForEach(Items.components.indices){ i in 
    synchronizedSlider(from: allBindings, index: i+1)
}
```

In broken code, what I want is something like:

```
ForEach(Items.component){component in
     HStack{
            Text("component.name")
Spacer()
synchronizedSlider(from: allBindings[$component.percentage], index: component.indexPosition)

      }
```

where allBindings[$component.percentage] is a binding array comprised of each itemComponent's percentage, and the index is an itemComponent's index.

I am happy to share more code if relevant. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To adapt the existing code you linked, if you're going to have a dynamic number of sliders, you'll definitely want your `@State` to be an array, rather than individual `@State` variables, which would have to be hard coded.

Once you have that, there are some minor syntax issues changing the `synchronizedBinding` functions to accept `Binding<[ItemComponent]>` rather than `[Binding<Double>]`, but they are pretty minor. Luckily, the existing code is pretty robust outside of the initial hard-coded states, so there isn't any additional math to do with the calculations.

I'm using `ItemComponent` rather than just `Double` because your sample code included it and having a model with a unique `id` makes the `ForEach` code I'm using for the sliders easier to deal with, since it expects uniquely-identifiable items.

```
struct ItemComponent: Hashable, Equatable, Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String = ""
    var percentage: Double
}

struct Sliders: View {
    
    @State var values : [ItemComponent] = [.init(name: "First", percentage: 100.0),.init(name: "Second", percentage: 0.0),.init(name: "Third", percentage: 0.0),.init(name:"Fourth", percentage: 0.0),]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                // Manually setting the values does not change the values such
                // that they sum to 100. Use separate algorithm for this
                self.values[0].percentage = 40
                self.values[1].percentage = 60
            }) {
                Text("Test")
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                self.values.append(ItemComponent(percentage: 0.0))
            }) {
                Text("Add slider")
            }
            
            Divider()
            
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(Array(values.enumerated()),id: \.1.id) { (index,value) in
                    Text(value.name)
                    Text("\(value.percentage)")
                    synchronizedSlider(from: $values, index: index)
                }
            }
            
        }.padding()
    }
    
    
    func synchronizedSlider(from bindings: Binding<[ItemComponent]>, index: Int) -> some View {
        return Slider(value: synchronizedBinding(from: bindings, index: index),
                      in: 0...100)
    }
    
    func synchronizedBinding(from bindings: Binding<[ItemComponent]>, index: Int) -> Binding<Double> {
        
        return Binding(get: {
            return bindings[index].wrappedValue.percentage
        }, set: { newValue in
            
            let sum = bindings.wrappedValue.indices.lazy.filter{ $0 != index }.map{ bindings[$0].wrappedValue.percentage }.reduce(0.0, +)
            // Use the 'sum' below if you initially provide values which sum to 100
            // and if you do not set the state in code (e.g. click the button)
            //let sum = 100.0 - bindings[index].wrappedValue
            
            let remaining = 100.0 - newValue
            
            if sum != 0.0 {
                for i in bindings.wrappedValue.indices {
                    if i != index {
                        bindings.wrappedValue[i].percentage = bindings.wrappedValue[i].percentage * remaining / sum
                    }
                }
            } else {
                // handle 0 sum
                let newOtherValue = remaining / Double(bindings.wrappedValue.count - 1)
                for i in bindings.wrappedValue.indices {
                    if i != index {
                        bindings[i].wrappedValue.percentage = newOtherValue
                    }
                }
            }
            bindings[index].wrappedValue.percentage = newValue
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. In the sample code, you initialize `values`. In my example,  I have an `@EnvironmentObject` called `Item` (as provided in the question) which collects a set of `ItemComponent` on a different `View`. Would it be possible to use these `ItemComponents` in `Items` instead of `values`? In this case, I would want the view to dynamically change the number of sliders (and bindings involved) as the collection of `ItemComponent` change in `Items`, and for the `percentage` of each `ItemComponent` to update in real time with the slider.

Comment: Sure. That would only be minor changes to the code I've made. I won't by sitting in front of my computer for a couple days. Have you tried adjusting it to fit your need? It's *very* similar to what I have and it would be a good exercise to adapt it to show moving around a `@Published` variable as a binding, etc.

Comment: Your response actually gave me just enough to figure out a working solution. A matter of switching `@State` to `@Binding`, and calling the Sliders view with `$items.component`, where `var items: Items()` seems to do the trick!

Comment: Cool. Feel free to upvote if it was helpful.